# Abordagem DataBase First com Lazy Loading desabilitado?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-first

Vou iniciar um projeto e a base de dados do `Sql Server` já existe então vou adotar a abordagem **Database First** conforme exemplo desse artigo [Entity Framework Tutorial](https://www.devmedia.com.br/entity-framework-tutorial/27764). 
Criarei o arquivo **.emdx** e importarei as respectivas tabelas TB_Cliente, TB_Endereco, TB_Produto, TB_Estoque e n outras tabelas associadas . 
Imaginemos que eu farei o seguinte:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    clienteCTX context = new clienteCTX();
    var _model = context.cliente.where(x => x.clienteID).ToList()
}
```

A query acima me retornará todas as Entidades associadas com a Entidade Cliente, correto ? 
Dúvida: posso **desabilitar** o `Lazy Loading` para que eu carregue na `expression lambda` apenas dados que realmente precisarei utilizando o `include` ? :

Se Sim como eu **desabilito** o `Lazy Loading` nesse cenário adotando o **DataBase First** ?

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais simples será desabilitar diretamente o `Lazy Loading`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    clienteCTX context = new clienteCTX()
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false
    };

    var _model = context.cliente.where(x => x.clienteID).ToList();
}
```

Penso que esta forma funcionará também em `Database First` (da mesma forma que funciona em `Code First`).

No **SOen** encontrei também esta forma, mas que nunca experimentei:

```
public static dynamic GetListaClientes()
{
    using (var context = new clienteCTX())
    {
        try
        {
            context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            return context.cliente.where(x => x.clienteID).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Link: [Entity Framework: How to disable lazy loading for specific query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022957/entity-framework-how-to-disable-lazy-loading-for-specific-query)